# JQUERY UI Dialog Modal - Is there a way to have the OVERLAY Div Persist? Or set which Div to Use?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

The reason I want this is so that when the overlay shows a WHITE Background, I can add "webkit-transition-duration" property to allow the white background to nicely fade-in and out using the GPU.

But problem here is that JQUERY seems to remove/add the overlay div every time the dialog is run.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure do not make the dialog modal and create the overlay yourself

set the option modal: false;

```
$(selector).dialog({
  modal: false
  open: function () {
     //create your own overlay div here.
  },
  close: function () {
     // remove your overlay div here.
  }
  //other options as needed
  });
```

now create the overlay div yourself.

Comment: I was afraid you'd say that :)

Comment: @noobish look above i edited my answer.  you could attempt to hijack the overlay div that jquery.dialog creates in the close method of the dialog.  Im pretty sure this wont work but maybe worth a try.  if all else fails. you can always create the overlay your self and then manipulate how it disapears in the close method.